# How to add back default Rinkeby Testnet network in brownie networks list back?

Tags: solidity, web3.py, rinkeby, brownie

I accidentally deleted the default rinkeby network that comes with brownie and wanted to know how to add it back? I tried with the below cmd by creating an infura project but I'm getting the `ValueError: Explorer API not set for this network` error even when I add
`publish_source=True` in my brownie config file. Without the public_source, I'm not able to verify my contract. It does get successfully deployed on Rinkeby Testnet.

`brownie networks add Ethereum rinkeby host='https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/34aa4a5993b44e00904f0ba64a27a156' chainid=4`

I tried with default Kovan Testnet and it worked after waiting for hours to get verified.

Answer (score 1):

For verifying a contract you need to mention the Explorer API in your network so you can add the network as:

```
brownie networks add Ethereum rinkeby host='https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/34aa4a5993b44e00904f0ba64a27a156' chainid=4
explorer='https://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api'
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! but its still giving `Explorer API not set for this network` error. I restarted a new infura project and it still gives the same error.